# VS2017 Performance Profiling Module Name Is GUID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, memory-leaks, profiling

Was performance profiling my software to see why memory usage is slowly growing regardless of GC, and found that the most memory-intensive function is an unnamed one (gave me a hex address) from an unknown module with a GUID for a name.

[image]

Googling the GUID gave literally no results (it was "{FAD2D840-B4A3-448C-8ED1-BA21B6695CDB}" in case anyone cares), and googling around to see if GUIDs showing up has some particular meaning also has no explanation readily available.

The next method down in exclusive bytes is 1/6 of the memory used by this one, so I'd really love to know what's using all of that.

Comment: With the function name being in hex, it might be that your heavy memory footprint is mostly in a native assembly. Does the class above make any calls to native code?

Comment: @Butler1233 Not really- I mean of course everything calls native code at some point down the rabbit hole, but nothing direct. There's plenty of reason for it to have large memory usage, as that's a busy method, but I would like to know what in particular is the culprit so I can optimize. There is a little "fire" icon next to a particular line of that function in the code but it is on a line that does something incredibly simple..

Comment: If adding more information would help, please let me know what I could add.